# Where to insert my Google translate API key in android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-translate

I am developing a android app which converts one language to another using Google translate API.I got a Google api key for translation from google .But i dont know where to put that key.In Main.xml or AndroidManifest.xml?? What should be the format please help me.

Thank you

Comment: For information, from Google's site:                      Important: The Google Translate API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. Due to the substantial economic burden caused by extensive abuse, the number of requests you may make per day will be limited and the API will be shut off completely on December 1, 2011.